# Difference between Activity.getLayoutInflator() vs Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)

Tags: android, android-activity, layout-inflater, android-context

I have a layout that defines an EditText with NO special style, theme or color, basically it uses the default one. The default one is OK.

I was inflating this layout from my Adapter using the [activity.getLayoutInflator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater()) and it was perfect, the way i wanted. But later I tried changing it to use the [context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) so i remove the direct reference to the activity. The it completely messes up the colors of the **hint** and **text color** of my EditText.

Initially I thought they were the same thing, just different ways of accessing it, but now i see that they produce different results, although the layout gets inflated successfully. WHY is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LayoutInflater` returned by `getLayoutInflater()` on `Activity` takes into account your app's theme; a `LayoutInflater` from some other `Context` and `getSystemService()` does not.

This is why, in the table in [Dave Smith's excellent blog post on `Context`](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/), you try to inflate layouts using an activity.